# When to use aws direct connect and aws storage gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services

> When to use aws direct connect and aws storage gateway. My question is these services seems to be similer, so what are use cases to use these two services.

Answer (score 4):

[AWS Direct Connect](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/direct-connect/?id=docs_gateway) is a network connection between AWS and on on-premises network. The physical connection is an optical fiber link organised through a Telco, while Direct Connect provisions the physical port where the fiber connects in an AWS transit center.

[AWS Storage Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/storage-gateway/?id=docs_gateway) is a storage service that provisions a virtual tape drive, virtual S3 drive or virtual disk that is stored in AWS. It typically **runs across a Direct Connect connection**.

Comment: from the AWS certification guide it is mentioned  "AWS Storage Gateway is a service connecting an on-premises software appliance with cloud-based storage to provide seamless and secure integration between an organization’s on-premises IT environment and the AWS storage infrastructure. " from the above explaination it does not seems to be a storage service. It also seems to be a connection between on-premises resourses and aws resources

Comment: Please refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/latest/userguide/using-dx.html

Answer (score 1):

AWS direct connect connect the in premisses resources with any services, while AWS storage gateway used to connects to S3 services including AWS S3 Glacier only.

This is one of the difference.

Answer (score 0):

"AWS Direct Connect is a network service that provides an alternative to using the Internet to connect customer's on-premise sites to AWS" ([AWS Docs](https://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/faqs/)).

"AWS Storage Gateway is a hybrid cloud storage service that gives you on-premises access to virtually unlimited cloud storage" ([AWS Docs](https://aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/faqs/)).

Direct Connect creates a *private network connection* btwn AWS and on-prem resources while **Storage** Gateway enables you to store and retrieve Amazon S3 objects through standard file storage protocol.

Answer (score 0):

**Storage Gateway** - As the name suggests, this service is used to connect on-premises infra with *STORAGE* services (specifically S3, FSx, EBS)

**Direct Connect** - This service is used to connect on-premises infra with any AWS resources (in any region)